# How can I merge these two SQL queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL queries and I don't have the experience to know how to combine them but they work individually.

This first query pulls only the first record for the given dates in the `SettlementDate` table

```
SELECT
    R.TradeDate,
    R.PromptIndicator,
    SUM(CASE WHEN S.PRODUCT = 69 AND R.PromptIndicator = 1 THEN R.VALUE ELSE NULL END) AS "WTI"
FROM 
    Argus.dbo.FC_Record AS R
INNER JOIN 
    Argus.dbo.SettlementDate AS S ON R.TradeDate = S.TradeDate 
                                  AND R.Product = S.Product
WHERE 
    R.Product = 69
    AND R.ValuationType = 3
    AND R.Term = 2
    AND R.PromptIndicator = 1
GROUP BY 
    R.TradeDate, R.PromptIndicator
ORDER BY 
    R.TradeDate ASC
```

The results from the first query look like this:

| TradeDate | PromptIndicator | WTI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/21/2020 | 1 | 58.34 |
| 02/20/2020 | 1 | 53.78 |
| 03/20/2020 | 1 | 22.43 |
| 04/21/2020 | 1 | 10.01 |
| 05/19/2020 | 1 | 32.5 |
| 06/22/2020 | 1 | 40.46 |
| 07/21/2020 | 1 | 41.96 |

Then the second query pulls in only the data for the most recent date, not necessarily in the `SettlementDate` table:

```
SELECT TOP 60 
    R.TradeDate,
    R.PromptIndicator,
    SUM(CASE WHEN R.PRODUCT = 69 THEN R.VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS "WTI"
FROM 
    Argus.dbo.FC_Record AS R
WHERE 
    R.Product = 69
    AND R.ValuationType = 3
    AND R.Term = 2
    AND R.PromptIndicator < 61
GROUP BY 
    R.TradeDate, R.PromptIndicator
ORDER BY 
    R.TradeDate DESC, R.PromptIndicator ASC
```

The results from the second query look like this:

| TradeDate | PromptIndicator | WTI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/23/2023 | 1 | 75.24 |
| 02/23/2023 | 2 | 75.39 |
| 02/23/2023 | 3 | 75.6 |
| 02/23/2023 | 4 | 75.68 |
| 02/23/2023 | 5 | 75.57 |
| 02/23/2023 | 6 | 75.33 |

And this is what I'm trying to get the result to look like:

| TradeDate | PromptIndicator | WTI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09/20/2022 | 1 | 84.45 |
| 10/20/2022 | 1 | 85.98 |
| 11/21/2022 | 1 | 79.73 |
| 12/20/2022 | 1 | 76.09 |
| 01/20/2023 | 1 | 81.31 |
| 02/21/2023 | 1 | 76.16 |
| 02/23/2023 | 1 | 75.24 |
| 02/23/2023 | 2 | 75.39 |
| 02/23/2023 | 3 | 75.6 |
| 02/23/2023 | 4 | 75.68 |
| 02/23/2023 | 5 | 75.57 |
| 02/23/2023 | 6 | 75.33 |

Using UNION gives this weird result:

| TradeDate | PromptIndicator | WTI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/21/2023 | 1 | 76.16 |
| 01/24/2023 | 43 | 65.8 |
| 01/20/2023 | 1 | 81.31 |
| 01/18/2023 | 29 | 69.6 |
| 12/20/2022 | 1 | 76.09 |
| 12/16/2022 | 7 | 74.04 |

Comment: You can use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` to merge the results as well as combine your queries since they are both using the same columns. [set-operators-union-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) , **(q1 union/union all q2)**

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Just a syntax note; When using `UNION` or `UNION ALL`, only a single `ORDER BY` clause is allowed at the end. If you really need to use `TOP 60` in the second query, I believe you will have to nest that in a subselect `SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 60 ... ORDER BY ...) A`. The combined  select would be `SELECT ... (with no order) UNION SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 60 ... ORDER BY ...) A ORDER BY ...`, where the final ORDER BY appies to the comete unioned results.

Comment: What is preventing FC_Record rows with PromptIndicator = 1 from appearing in the results of both queries?

Comment: And a side note: Are you sure that Product and TradeDate unambiguouusly defined the relationship between FC_Record and SettlementDate? What if two trades are requested on the same date (or even same dattime)? (Hopefully you have a distinct trade ID that you've just left out to simplify your question.).

Comment: @TN - I need PromptIndicator = 1 in both queries. In the second query, I need PromptIndicator = (1-60). There is no distinct trade ID. The `SettlementDate` table has columns [Product] and [TradeDate]. The `FC_RECORD` table has columns [Product], [TradeDate], [PromptIndicator], [Value], [ValuationType], [Term], and several others.

Comment: @gwhb - Cut and paste the table contents as text (instead of an image0 into your question, preferably formatted as a markdown table. If you don't know how to format markdown tables, you can post as preformatted text. Someone may edit it afterwards.  It would also be useful to post the table schemas and sample data, so that others have something to work from. Ideally, put together a working example that combines schema, data, and query in a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-). That will maximize your chance of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Regarding "Using UNION gives this weird result", did you nest the "top 60" query as I suggested above, with an ORDER BY both inside the subquery (which defined the top 60 priority) *and* at the end (which defines the final result ordering)?

Comment: @TN - No, I did not nest it properly so that makes sense. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There may be ways to write a simplified single query using `WHERE (common conditions) AND (R.PromptIndicator = 1 OR (R.PromptIndicator < 61 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SettlementDate WHERE ...)))` but the `TOP 60` criteria in the second part would significantly complicate this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your 2 queries both work and have the same fields, put each in a CTE and combine them with UNION ALL

```
--NOTE: The preceding line MUST termintate with (the normally optional) ; or the WITH will fail!
with cteQ1 as (
SELECT
    R.TradeDate,
    R.PromptIndicator,
    SUM(CASE WHEN S.PRODUCT = 69 AND R.PromptIndicator = 1 THEN R.VALUE ELSE NULL END) AS "WTI"
FROM 
    Argus.dbo.FC_Record AS R
INNER JOIN 
    Argus.dbo.SettlementDate AS S ON R.TradeDate = S.TradeDate 
                                  AND R.Product = S.Product
WHERE 
    R.Product = 69
    AND R.ValuationType = 3
    AND R.Term = 2
    AND R.PromptIndicator = 1
GROUP BY 
    R.TradeDate, R.PromptIndicator
--Don't order inside the CTE unless you're using TOP --ORDER BY R.TradeDate ASC
), cteQ2 as (
    SELECT TOP 60 
    R.TradeDate,
    R.PromptIndicator,
    SUM(CASE WHEN R.PRODUCT = 69 THEN R.VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS "WTI"
FROM 
    Argus.dbo.FC_Record AS R
WHERE 
    R.Product = 69
    AND R.ValuationType = 3
    AND R.Term = 2
    AND R.PromptIndicator < 61
GROUP BY 
    R.TradeDate, R.PromptIndicator
ORDER BY 
    R.TradeDate DESC, R.PromptIndicator ASC
)SELECT * FROM cteQ1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cteQ2
```